# Loop from php array dispaly carousel 6 items per page

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I have an associative array or object

**example:**

How can I loop over the array too display carousel to output in such html output

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">                    
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="images/img4.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="images/img5.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5"><img src="images/img6.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                            </div><!--.row-->
                        </div><!--.item-->              
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="images/img4.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="images/img5.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                              <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5"><img src="images/img6.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                            </div><!--.row-->
                        </div><!--.item-->
                    </div><!--.carousel-inner-->
                  <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
                  <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
                </div><!--.Carousel-->
```

I have tried:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">     

                   <?php 
                      echo "<div class='item active'>";
                      echo "<div class='row'>";
                        foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
                            if ($key== 6) {
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "<div class='item'>";
                                echo "<div class='row'>";
                            }
                             echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";
                             echo '<a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-'.$key.'"><img src="images/img'.$value.'.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>';
                            echo "</div>";
                        }
                    echo "</div>";  
                    echo "</div>";?>
```

Comment: that array is not multidimensional, it's just one dimension. and are you telling me you don't know how `for` and `foreach` loops work?

Comment: Can you show us your variable content ? what do you get when you do var_export($arr); ?

Comment: @Bang where does that happen? or was that part of some edit i missed? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop code was pretty close ; all you needed was a modulo operator.

If you don't know what modulo is, you can read up here : http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

```
<?php 
  echo "<div class='item active'>";
  echo "<div class='row'>";
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
    {
        //if we can divide $key by six without remainder
        if ($key % 6 == 0) 
        {
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='item'>";
            echo "<div class='row'>";
        }
         echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";
         echo '<a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-'.$key.'"><img src="images/img'.$value.'.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>';
        echo "</div>";
    }
echo "</div>";  
echo "</div>";?>
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not simple like that , the first 6 items are in  <div class="item active"> only.

Comment: Ok, but the other one seems to have the exact same content. are you just looking to limit the maximum length of the iteration?

Comment: So you want to use 6 maximum per row?

Comment: alright, you were pretty close with your first try. try this ; (i updated the answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70840/discussion-between-soksan-and-timothy-groote).

Comment: the first 6 items not appear,

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of a correct answer:

```
<?php
$result .= '<div class="item active">';
    foreach ($get_result as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !=0 && ($key % 6 == 0)) { //to avoid first empty "active"
          $result .= "</div>";
          $result .= "<div class='item'>";
        }

        $result .= '<a href="'.$value['url'].'"><img src="'.$value['logo'].'" alt="'.$value['name'].'" title="'.$value['name'].'"></a>';
    }
    $result .= '</div>';
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: @mathielo Actually, this is an answer, but the description made it seem like it was intended as a comment.  This has been changed.

Comment: Thank you! Firstly it was like comment to Timothy Groote's answer, because in his version there was empty "active" item. But I hope my version will help someone :)

Comment: @Thanks Sergey.it helped me a lot